# Can C arrays contain padding in between elements?

Tags: c, arrays, padding

I heard a rumor that, in C, arrays that are contained inside structs may have padding added in between elements of the array. Now obviously, the amount of padding could not vary between any pair of elements or calculating the next element in an array is not possible with simple pointer arithmetic.

This rumor also stated that arrays which are not contained in structures are guaranteed to contain no padding. I know at least that part is true.

So, in code, the rumor is:

```
{
    // Given this:
    struct { int values[20]; } foo;
    int values[20];

    // This may be true:
    sizeof(values) != sizeof(foo.values);
}
```

I'm pretty certain that `sizeof(values)` will always equal `sizeof(foo.values)`. However, I have not been able to find anything in the C standard (specifically C99) that explicitly confirms or denies this.

Does anyone know if this rumor is addressed in any C standard?

**edit**: I understand that there may be padding between the end of the array `foo.values` and the end of the struct `foo` and that the standard states that there will be no padding between the start of `foo` and the start of `foo.values`. However, does anyone have a *quote from* or *reference to* the standard where it says there is no padding between the elements of `foo.values`?

Comment: I don't have any references for this, but I'm quite sure that I've read that the compiler are free to align structs as it likes. Generally this will probably be done in the manner that cletus describes.

Comment: seems a lot of ppl miss that the comparsion is between the two arrays and not between array/struct. sizeof(values) != sizeof(foo); this is _not_ what he do, but what ppl seem to think in some answers

Answer (score 43, accepted):

No, there will never be padding in between elements of an array. That is specifically not allowed. The C99 standard calls array types "An array type describes a contiguously allocated nonempty set of objects...". For contrast, a structure is "sequentially", not "contiguously" allocated.

There might be padding before or after an array within a structure; that is another animal entirely. The compiler might do that to aid alignment of the structure, but the C standard doesn't say anything about that.

Comment: Depends on what you mean. A compiler can add padding to the end of struct (see my example). If you take such a struct, and make an array of it, there are unused bytes between used bytes, but each element of the array is always sizeof(T) bytes after the previous one. But sizeof(T.a) + sizeof(T.b) + ... may not equal sizeof(T).

Comment: "The sizeof comparison you are making could pick that up" No? compair is between the two arrays, not between array and struct

Comment: @Thanatos - I basically agree, except that if the compiler adds bytes to the end of the structure, that is included in the sizeof. Sizeof is on a type, not an instance of that type, and the type doesn't know if it's used in an array or not.

Comment: Thanks for the  quote. It comes from section 6.2.5 paragraph 20 for anyone interested in looking it up.

Answer (score 13):

Careful here.  Padding may be added at the end of the struct, but will not be added between the elements of the array as you state in your question.  Arrays will always reference contiguous memory, though an array of structures may have padding added to each element as part of the struct itself.

In your example, the `values` and `foo.values` arrays will have the same size.  Any padding will be part of the struct `foo` instead.

Answer (score 4):

Here's the explanation as to *why* a structure may need padding between its members or even after its last member, and why an array doesn't:

Different types might have different alignment requirements. Some types need to be aligned on word boundaries, others on double or even quad word boundaries. To accomplish this, a structure may contain padding bytes between its members. Trailing padding bytes might be needed because the memory location directly ofter a structure must also conform to the structure's alignment requirements, ie if `bar` is of type `struct foo *`, then

```
(struct foo *)((char *)bar + sizeof(struct foo))
```

yields a valid pointer to `struct foo` (ie doesn't fail due to mis-alignment).

As each 'member' of an array has the same alignment requirement, there's no reason to introduce padding. This holds true for arrays contained in structures as well: If an array's first elment is correctly aligned, so are all following elements.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, sort of. Variables are often aligned to some boundry, depending on the variable. Take the following, for instance:

```
typedef struct
{
    double d;
    char c;
} a_type_t;
```

double and char are 8 and 1 bytes, on my system, respectively. Total of 9. That structure, however, will be 16 bytes, so that the doubles will always be 8-byte aligned. If I had just used ints, chars, etc, then the alignment might be 1, 2, 4, or 8.

For some type T, `sizeof(T)` *may or may not equal* `sizeof(T.a) + sizeof(T.b) + sizeof(T.c) ...` etc.

Generally, this is entirely compiler and architecture dependent. In practice, it never matters.

Comment: @Rom Why doesn't it never matter? I think the issue is directly related to the problem of **false sharing**. For example - when there is an array of structures or even basic types and each thread has an entry assigned in this array to where that thread is frequently writing. Then it would be useful to keep the array elements at different cache lines, else possibly each write could mean a cache miss in the currently writing thread.

Answer (score -1):

Consider:

```
struct {
  short s;
  int i;
} s;
```

Assuming shorts are 16 bits and you're on 32 bits, the size will *probably* be 8 bytes as each struct members tends to be aligned a word (32 bit in this case) boundary. I say "probably" because it is implementation specific behaviour that can be varied by compiler flags and the like.

It's worth stressing that this is implementation behaviour not necessarily defined by the C standard. Much like the size of shorts, ints and longs (the C standard simply says shorts won't be larger than ints and longs won't be smaller than ints, which can end up as 16/32/32, 16/32/64, 32/32/64 or a number of other configurations).

Comment: In ARM-based machine it will do, but it is also very dangerous, as ARM does not perform alignment checks

Comment: Actually, I believe on x86 and amd64 machines, that will have a size of 6, for gcc compilers -- there is no benefit for a char to be 8 byte aligned. But as you mention, this in compiler dependent.

Comment: The size is 8 on x86 and amd64 machines with gcc.  I agree this is compiler dependent; in the example in this answer the issue is the natural alignment of an int.