# Best way to compare two int arrays of the same length?

Tags: c, arrays, compare, int, c99

what is the best way to compare int arrays b and c with a:

```
int a[] = {0,1,0,0,1};
int b[] = {0,1,0,0,1};
int c[] = {1,1,0,0,1};
```

b and c are just examples, assume they can be any combination of 0s and 1s.

I am trying to detect arrays identical to a. I have googled this for a while and have not found a satisfactory answer.

This is a beginners question I realise, thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Use the standard `memcmp` function from `<string.h>`.

```
memcmp(a, b, sizeof(a)) == 0
```

whenever `a` and `b` are equal.

Comment: Minor note:  If there are padding bits in the `int` type, `memcmp()` may yield a false negative.  Fortunately, the OP is unlikely to run across such implementations.

Comment: @J.C.Salomon: What are "padding bits in the `int` type"?

Comment: Using memcmp in this case in C is not reliable because of possible padding bits.

Comment: Except of course that [arrays may not contain padding between elements](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1066719/212858)

Comment: @Useless That is true, but it is also a red herring. I was talking about padding bits in integers themselves.

Comment: You think there are secret un-initialized bits _inside_ an `int`? Perhaps you could give an actual example of what you mean - in fact, ideally ask (and answer, if you like) a question rather than continuing this in comments.

Comment: @Useless: Some machines (especially DSPs) have an accumulator whose size is a not a multiple of a memory word [one might have a 16-bit memory word but a 40-bit accumulator].  In some cases, it may be helpful for them to define a type whose useful portion is not a multiple of the word size [e.g. such a platform could define "long" as three bytes long, but with only 40 bits holding useful information].

Answer (score 6):

If you mean

```
int a[] = {0,1,0,0,1};
int b[] = {0,1,0,0,1};
int c[] = {1,1,0,0,1};
```

then

```
memcmp(a, b, sizeof(a)); /* returns zero for a match */
memcmp(a, c, sizeof(a)); /* returns nonzero for no match */
```

Comment: Using memcmp in this case in C is not reliable because of possible padding bits.

Answer (score 5):

Use a loop and compare the individual elements one after another.

Comment: don't forget to escape the loop when you reach the end of one of the arrays, in case the size is different

Answer (score 1):

More information is needed on the question.
I can divide your question in two ways as below,

1. Compare array contents considering order??
   **Ex:char a[]={a, b, c}, b[]={a, c, b} here since you are considering the order, the contents are not same so *a!=b***

---

2. compare array contents irrespective of order?
   **Ex:char a[]={a, b, c}, b[]={a, c, b}
   here if you are not considering the order, the contents are same so *a==b***

---

**Solution for Question no 1:**
One can use memcmp for this problem. Because *memcmp* will compare lexicographical and return 0 or 1 or -1 as below

```
 #include<stdio.h>
    #include<string.h>
    int main()
    {

        char a[]={'a','b','c'};
        char b[]={'a','b','c'};
        int x=memcmp(a,b,sizeof(a));
        printf("%d\n",x);

    return 0;
    }
***output:0***

    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<string.h>
    int main()
    {

        char a[]={'a','c','b'};
        char b[]={'a','b','c'};
        int x=memcmp(a,b,sizeof(a));
        printf("%d\n",x);

    return 0;
    }
***output:1***

    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<string.h>
    int main()
    {

        char a[]={'a','b','c'};
        char b[]={'b','a','c'};
        int x=memcmp(a,b,sizeof(a));
        printf("%d\n",x);

    return 0;
    }
***output:-1***
```

**Solution for Question no 2:**
One can use memcmp for this problem, the best solution for this problem is as below

Here, I answered for the above problem
https://stackoverflow.com/a/36130812/5206646

Answer (score 0):

For performance reasons memcmp() will compare byte for byte while int arrays are in 4 byte chunks. This will most likely be pretty slow if the array is large or you have to compare many arrays.

The simplest way is to run a for loop that exits as soon as you find a difference.

```
bool is_array_equal(const int * a, const int * b, length){
    for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i){
        if(a[i] != b[i]){ return false; }
    }
    return true;
}
```