# How to check if all the elements from array1 are in array2?

Tags: c, arrays

I need to write a program that checks if two arrays are *equal*, meaning that  elements from array1 are all in array2. It is possible, that elements are in different rows and columns, but all the elements from the first array need to be in the second array. I wrote the code below:

```
 #include <stdio.h>

int fun(int m, int tab1[][m], int tab2[][m], int n)
{
    int i, j, k, p, itis = 0;

    if(itis == 0)
    {
        for(i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
            for(j=0; j<m; j++)
            {
                int elem = tab2[i][j];

                for(k=0; k<n; k++)
                {
                    for(p=0; p<m; p++)
                    {
                        if(tab1[k][m] == elem)
                        {
                            itis = 1;
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }

    return itis;
}

int main()
{

    int tab1[][3] = {{1,2,3}, {4,5,6}, {7,8,9}};
    int tab2[][3] = {{7,8,9}, {1,2,3}, {4,5,6}};
    int tab3[][3] = {{0,0,0}, {0,0,0}, {0,0,1}};

    int tab4[][3] = {{7,8,9}, {1,2,3}, {4,5,0}};

    printf("%d\n", fun(3, tab1, tab4, 3));

    return 0;
}
```

My function should return 1 if all the elements from the first array are present in the second array (could be in different order - rows/columns). But for `tab1` and `tab4` I got `1`, instead of `0`. (in  `tab1` there's 6, but 6 is not in `tab4`). Any ideas?

Comment: Shouldn't that be if(tab1[k][p] == elem) ... ? However, the current code only  checks for a single match. You could increment a count for each match found, then check to see if the count == m*n .

Comment: Your code doesn't define `tab4` but your question mentions it.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9120065/best-way-to-compare-two-int-arrays-of-the-same-length for inspiration

Comment: Generally: Flatten, sort, compare.

Answer (score 1):

```
int fun(int m, int tab1[][m], int tab2[][m], int n){
    int *element1 = &tab1[0][0];//top element
    int *endp1    = element1 + n*m;//end element
    int *element2 = &tab2[0][0];
    int *endp2    = element2 + n*m;
    int itis = 0, *p;

    for(;element1 != endp1; ++element1){
        itis = 0;
        for(p = element2; p != endp2; ++p){
            if(*p == *element1){
                itis = 1;//found!
                break;
            }
        }
        if(itis==0)//not found
            return itis;//0
    }
    return itis;//1: all exist
}
```