# How to compare two arrays in C programming language?

Tags: c, arrays

I want to compare two different arrays which are both `int`. One array is static and contains numbers from 1 to 10 and second arrays asks user to enter ten different numbers and the program checks which elements from both arrays are equal.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int array1[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
    int array2[10];
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
        printf("Enter numbers: ");
        scanf("%d", &array2);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
        if (array1[i] != array2[i]) {
            printf("Not equal \n");
        } else {
            printf("They are equal. \n");
        }
    }
}
```

The program always say not equal even if I enter a number that is equal to a number stored in first array.

Comment: What did you enter, what did you see, what did you expect to see?

Comment: memcmp is an option.

Comment: Also, you are writing to the same array2 index each time you get input.

Comment: You are accessing out of bounds - the arrays have size 10 so the loop condition should be `i  < 10`, not `i < 11`.  Also you meant `&array2[i]` in the scanf line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
scanf("%d", &array2);
```

You are never updating the index of `array2` when getting a value from input.

Try

```
scanf("%d", &array2[i]);
```

As for comparing, you can also use `memcmp` to compare memory:

```
memcmp(array1, array2, sizeof(array1));
```

Comment: Care to add some specifics? Sure, bit padding could be a concern I suppose, but I've rarely seen it and not in a scenario like this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9120065/best-way-to-compare-two-int-arrays-of-the-same-length

Comment: OP is using C, C allows padding bits, which can cause an incorrect memcmp result. Since OP didn't specify that he is using a platform without padding bits, but posted the question in relation to the C Programming language. See title and tag. (Please use @ or I won't be reading your responses. )

Answer (score 3):

Arrays use zero based indices for a start. You are incorrectly populating `array2` so you probably want to change your first loop to the following

```
    for (i=0;i<10;i++) 
    {
            printf("Enter numbers: ");
            scanf("%d", &array2[i]);
    }
```

as your current code is simply passing the address of `array2` as argument to `scanf`.

Then change the second loop conditional to

```
 for (i=0;i<10;i++)
```

in your comparison loop so that you do not access items beyond your array boundaries.

Currently your second loop is accessing items at indices 0 to 10 - but there are only 10 items present in `array1` so you have undefined behaviour with your current code.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {

        int array1[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
        int array2[10];
        int i;

        for (i=0;i<10;i++) { //fixed the range here

                printf("Enter numbers: ");
                scanf("%d", &array2[i]); //fixed the indexing
        }

        for (i=0;i<10;i++) { //fixed the range here

                if (array1[i] != array2[i]) {

                        printf("Not equal \n");
                }
                else {
                        printf("They are equal. \n");
                }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I am a beginner and I have this idea about comparing two arrays. Hope It might help someone like me.

```
/***compare two array: all elements are same or not(if not sorted)***/

#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    
    int array1[n], array2[n];
    int i, j;
    
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &array1[i]);
    }
    
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &array2[i]);
    }
    
    int flg=0;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<n; j++)
        {
            if(array1[i] == array2[j])
            {
                flg += 1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if(flg == n)
    {
        printf("All The Elements of array1 is present in array2... :)");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("All THe Elements of array1 is not present in array2 :(");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This does not work if there are duplicate elements in either array: for example if on array has `n` times the first element of the other, the diagnostic `All The Elements of array1 is present in array2` will be incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to respond to the answer, even though I am a beginner to C program.

According to your program written above, you are inputting and holding values to `int array2[10]` which has 11 elements.

Remember that the first element of this array is indexed by zero. Ex: `array2[0]`, until it reaches the last element which is `array2[10]`, you have counted 11.

Now `array1` has the pre-defined values write which will be compared to your input values.  Enter and store your values into `array2[]`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int array1[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    int array2[10];
    int i;

    for (i=0;i<10;i++) { //fixed the range here
        printf("Enter numbers: ");
        scanf("%d", &array2[i]); //fixed the indexing

        if (array1[i] != array2[i]) {
            printf("Not equal \n");
        }
        else {
            printf("They are equal. \n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It may actually be more useful to do `for (i=0;i<(sizeof(array1)/sizeof(int));i++)` instead of `for (i=0;i<10;i++)`