# Can an array have trailing padding?

Tags: arrays, c, language-lawyer, padding

Given a quiz question "What's the value returned by the following function:".

```c
size_t f(int *a[2][3][4]) {
  return sizeof(*a);
}
```

Is the answer `sizeof(int *) * 3 * 4` correct?
By which I mean:
Is the following equality guaranteed by the ISO C standard?

```c
sizeof(int *) * 3 * 4 == sizeof(int*[3][4])
```

I've searched the standard far and wide and came to the same conclusion as the askee of
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27093290/can-an-array-have-trailing-padding) question. Except their examples and accepted answer talk about an array of arrays. But there cannot be padding between elements of arrays to begin with.

My question is, no matter why. Could an array have trailing bytes that would disrupt the above mentioned equality?

Update:
It was asked where did the `[2]` go. Since `a` is an argument of a function, its type is actually `int *(*)[3][4]`. See [6.7.6.3p7](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.6.3p7)

Comment: What happened to the `[2]` though? It's in the original code, then disappears in the analysis.

Comment: @pmacfarlane please see my update explaining the missing [2].

Comment: Yes, that's a good update and explains it.

Comment: @cafce25 In the argument `a` is declared as a `array 2 of array 3 of array 4 of pointer to int` see [here](https://cdecl.org/?q=int+*a%5B2%5D%5B3%5D%5B4%5D)
Since its an argument of a function, `a` is `pointer to array 3 of array 4 of pointer to int`
see [here](https://cdecl.org/?q=int+*%28*a%29%5B3%5D%5B4%5D)
But I don't believe this is relevant to the asked question so I wont edit it further.

Comment: You're right, C types are hard...

Answer (score 3):

According to the C standard, the size of an array is equal to the number of elements in the array multiplied by the size of each element.

In the case of the f() function, the size of `*a` is equal to `sizeof(int*) * 3 * 4`, as the type of `*a` is `int*[3][4]`, which is an array of 3 arrays of 4 int* elements.

The standard does not specify any padding between elements of an array, so the equality `sizeof(int *) * 3 * 4 == sizeof(int*[3][4])` is guaranteed to hold.

It is worth noting that the standard does allow for padding between structure members and at the end of a structure, and it is possible for the size of a structure to be larger than the sum of the sizes of its members due to padding. However, this does not apply to arrays.

Update: it was pointed out that the `[2]` disappeared from OPs questions.

The size of an array is determined by the number of elements in the array and the size of each element. In the case of `int*[2][3][4]`, the size of the array is equal to `2 * 3 * 4 * sizeof(int*)`, as there are 2 arrays of 3 arrays of 4 int* elements.

When you use the `sizeof` operator on a type such as `int*[3][4]`, it returns the size of that type, which is equal to `3 * 4 * sizeof(int*)`. The size of the outer array (`int*[2][3][4]`) is not included in this calculation, as `*a` has type `int*[3][4]`, not `int*[2][3][4]`.

In other words, `sizeof(*a)` is equivalent to `sizeof(int*[3][4])`, not `sizeof(int*[2][3][4])`.

The behavior of the sizeof operator and the way in which the size of an array is determined are specified in section 6.5.3.4 of the ISO C standard.

Here is the relevant text from the standard:

> The sizeof operator yields the size (in bytes) of its operand, which
> may be an expression or the parenthesized name of a type. The size is
> determined from the type of the operand. The result is an integer. If
> the type of the operand is a variable length array type, the operand
> is evaluated; otherwise, the operand is not evaluated and the result
> is an integer constant.
>
> The size of a struct or union is the sum of the sizes of its members, > including any padding.

This means that the size of an array is equal to the number of elements in the array multiplied by the size of each element, and the sizeof operator returns the size of the type it is applied to.

Some more information can be found here, too: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof

Comment: Ditto to the comment on the OP. Where did the `[2]` disappear to?

Comment: The beginning of the array can be aligned.

Comment: @pmacfarlane please see my update. Correct me if I am wrong, tho. You make me question myself..

Comment: @Max I think you're right, and well spotted. Have upvoted.

Comment: I would also cite this part of the standard to proof the claim

Comment: @0___________ good point, going to add it.

Comment: I would like one more citation for the initial claim "the size of an array is equal to the number of elements in the array multiplied by the size of each element". Notably the section 6.2.5p20 of the ISO C standard may be quoted. Is the lack of any padding implied by the word "contiguously"?