# can we access the array's deeper elements directly if we know the memory address?

Tags: arrays, c, multidimensional-array, data-structures, memory-management

In logic, for a 3d array, we need to access the outer array first and work our way inside inside each dimension and access th array's element. Since, physical memory store arrays as a block of memory irrespective of its dimensions, can we directly access using it address as there are ways to get a memory location?

If a multi dimensional array is stored in physical memory as a 1d array, can we access the array's deeper elements directly if we know the memory address?

Comment: it is c language

Comment: How is the array defined?

Comment: If it s a true 3D array then yes, all you need is the start address and array dimensions to be able to access all elements in the array. In fact, the array `[]` notation is just convenience syntax and translates to the same memory address calculations.

Comment: Say you have an `array[x][y][z]` where `x`, `y`, `z` are the dimensions. To work from the outer 2D arrays in, you can do `int i = 0, j = x-1;` and then `while (i < j) { /* work with array[j][y][z] and array[i][y][z], then i++, j-- */ }` You add a special case of `i == j` and only process the final 2D array once if `x` is odd.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly see a 3D array `int arr[a][b][c]` as a "flattened" 1D array `int flattened[a * b * c]` and access its elements accordingly.

```c
int arr[3][4][5];

int * flattened = &arr[0][0][0];
```

Element `arr[i][j][k]` would correspond to `flattened[b * c * i + c * j + k]`.

It is even well-defined behavior since [array elements are guaranteed to be contiguous in memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066681/can-c-arrays-contain-padding-in-between-elements).