# How to read the syntax of a C++ Bitfield definition?

Tags: c++, bit-fields

I need some help in understanding the syntax of a Bitfield definition. I read the Microsoft documentation page on it but the example there still leaves me with my question. Given a Bitfield and main method like this:

```
struct {
    unsigned short character : 8;
    unsigned short color     : 4;
} text[80];

int main() {
    text[20].character = 'a';
    text[20].color = 5;
}
```

For better reference of what I'm asking, here numbered:

1. What do the `[80]` and the `[20]`'s mean here?
2. Does `text[80]` mean an array of 80 such structs?
3. Does `text[20].character = 'a'` mean, that at position 20 of the array there is a character `'a'`?

Comment: All of those questions look unrelated to bit fields. As in you could remove the bit fields and have the same questions.

Answer (score 1):

*"What do the `[80]` and the `[20]`'s mean here?"*

`text[80];` declares an array with 80 elements and `text[20]` accesses the 21st element.

*"Does `text[80]` mean an array of 80 such structs?"*

Yes.

*"Does `text[20].character = 'a'` mean, that at position 20 of the array there is a character 'a'?"*

Yes.

Answer (score 1):

> What do the [80] and the [20]'s mean here?

The [80] means defining an array of the anonymous type that you defined(the defined structure).
let me clearly tell what is happening. As *unsigned short* is 16 bits, this struct will be a 16 bits memory that first 8 bits are named as the character, and the 4 middle bits are named as color, and 4 ending bits are not used.

You created an array of 80 elements from this structure. It means you have 80 consecutive 16 bit in the memory; each of these elements(16 bit) has a character(8 bit) and a color(4 bit) and 4 unused bit.

Bitfield is very useful in low-level software and embedded systems. For example in your scenario, it seems a consumer waiting for data that its 8 first bits will be treated as a character(ASCII), and its 4 next bits are treated as the color of that character. So your 80 element array means 80 characters that have its own color.

Comment: _"As unsigned short is 16 bits"_ `unsigned short` has at least 2 byte. It can be larger. _"It means you have 80 consecutive 16 bit in the memory"_ that's not necessary true. The compiler is allowed to add padding.

Comment: @ThomasSablik First, regarding unsigned short, based on the standard, you right, it will be at least 16 bit. but based on https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types I saw that in LP32, ILP32, LLP64, LP64 implementations the size of unsigned short will be 16 bit.

Comment: @ThomasSablik Second, regarding padding between array element I'm sure it is not there out of the box. Because if we had padding between array element then we couldn't able to easily convert array to pointer. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/1066719/10514096

Comment: _"I saw that in LP32, ILP32, LLP64, LP64 implementations the size of unsigned short will be 16 bit."_ But in other implementations it can be larger. You can have padding before `character` and between `character` and `color`

Comment: @ThomasSablik before character maybe, but between character and color as here bitfield used, so I don't think we have any padding between these two.

Comment: A compiler developer is allowed to add this padding and that would be valid behavior. A compiler developer is allowed to make `unsigned short` 8 bytes. That makes your answer wrong.

Comment: The compiler is allowed to do it even though it doesn't make sense for you.

Comment: @ThomasSablik First, the compiler allocates the first bitfield in 16bits(or more memory); so we have a 16bits(or more) that only the first 8 bit used and 8 ending bits(or more) are free; then the compiler tries to allocate the 'color' that is 4 bit and as it is unsigned short(the same type as the 'character'), so the compiler will store these 4 bits in the previous unsigned short.After the compiler tries to align this struct; as it is 16 bits(12 used + 4 unused) it will be aligned as 16 bits and padding will be neglected(the 4 unused bit will behave as padding)

Comment: @ThomasSablik please check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment and http://www.c-faq.com/struct/align.html

Comment: I can't find why it shouldn't be allowed to add a padding. AFAIK it makes no sense to add padding but the compiler could do it.

Comment: @ThomasSablik I agree with you, the compiler allowed to pad; but AFAIK, compiler padding in the data structure for alignment. If the structure is aligned, why the compiler does extra padding? (that is really unusable)

Comment: Ok your answer describes a special case where `short` has 2 bytes and there is no padding. But that's not the general case.

Comment: @ThomasSablik The title of this question is not about structure padding. It is a special case! Even if the unsigned short will be 32 or 64 bits, again it is true; Except 4 bit unused will be increased.

Comment: OP didn't provide their system and compiler. You don't know if your answer is correct. It could be the one system with 16 bytes `short` and 16 bytes padding between all member variables. In that case each array element would have a size 48 bytes.

Comment: @ThomasSablik I don't reject your opinion, because I'm not a master in all compilers! But as standard told, unsigned short should be 16,32 or 64 bit. As padding idea applied for, it came for help on alignment. So there is no reason that the compiler behaves vice and versa.

Comment: _"But as standard told, unsigned short **should be** 16,32 or 64 bit"_ but it doesn't need to. _"I'm not a master in all compilers"_ You don't have to know all compilers. The standard allows it therefore your answer is compiler specific and without knowing OP's compiler your answer could be wrong.